# How to use multiprocess in decorator

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to create a decorator which make function accept single argument to deal with iterable arguments parallel.

Here is the example code:

```py
import functools
import time

from multiprocessing import Pool

def parallel(func):

    def wrapper(iterable):
        with Pool() as pool:
            result = pool.map(func, iterable)

        return result

    return wrapper

@parallel
def test(i):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f"{i}: {i * i}")


def main():
    test(range(10))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/projects/amdb/s2.py", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user/projects/amdb/s2.py", line 25, in main
    test(range(10))
  File "/home/user/projects/amdb/s2.py", line 10, in wrapper
    result = pool.map(func, iterable)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 367, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 774, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 540, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function test at 0x7fef63309120>: it's not the same object as __main__.test
```

I know I could fix this by not using decorator, something like `test_multi = parallel(test)` , but the problem is how to use it in decorator.

Answer (score 1):

This is because multiprocessing.Pool needs to be able to serialize functions and parameters to pass between processes, and the decorator @parallel makes it impossible to serialize the test function correctly.You can use the `pathos` library, which is an extension of `multiprocessing`, which can serialize more types, including functions. Remember to install it before using. `pip install pathos`

Code:

```py
import time

from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessPool


def parallel(func):
    def wrapper(iterable):
        with ProcessPool() as pool:
            result = pool.map(func, iterable)

        return result

    return wrapper


@parallel
def test(i):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f"{i}: {i * i}")


def main():
    test(range(10))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```